# Can Apache 2.2.24 from MacPorts 2.1.3 run stably on Server 10.6.8 Build 10K549 with symlinked targets?

Tags: osx-server, macports, apache, symlink

- Mac OS X Server 10.6.8 Build 10K549 running Apache 2.2.24 via MacPorts 2.1.3.
- Native Mac OS X Server http server disabled.

The error message I'm getting in the log is as follows:

```
[Tue Aug 13 11:21:55 2013] [error] [client {removed}] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: {removed}
```

I have a DocumentRoot setting that involves a symbolic link. This works fine, but after an X amount of hours, something happens (I haven't figured out what, looked at every log possible) which prevents the daemon from entering the symbolic link. I checked file permissions (both ACL and POSIX) for any changes, but nothing seems faulty.

Now the really stupefying part: after a simple restart of the apache daemon, it works fine again. This cycle goes on and on. I checked the server configuration for any runtime changes, but none are applied. It's really frustrating a simple restart resolves the issue, because I lose all grip on the issue at hand.

Has anyone found a way to troubleshoot this or better yet - actually solve the instability?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? Is there anything in any other log file which might help to understand what's going on?

Comment: Why are some tags removed and why is this question moved to AskDifferent? This is less a Mac software / hardware issue and more a server management issue. Also, the tags "macosxserver", "permissions" and "apache2" shouldn't had been removed, this question is not less about these than "symlink" or "macports".

Comment: @patrix I updated the question with the error message, thanks!